# Zend Framework 2 MVC - Modules Route mapping not working

Tags: zend-framework2

I try to follow [Akrabats Tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2-tutorial/) the Application/Index is working, the Album part not.

I tried it also with the [ZendSkeletonModule](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule) with no luck.

The error in both cases is:

`album/album (resolves to invalid controller class or alias: album/album)`

I tried it with ZF2 master and beta4 tag (but beta4 tag gives php error about missing method getEventManager)

I took the code from Akrabats Tutorial, and after that failed used the code form the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/akrabat/zf2-tutorial). Unfortunatly there isnt some Forum or Comment section to ask for help.

I found some diffrences in the tutorial and the Skeleton (zfcUser has the same diffrence) in the module.config.php (which i believe is the core of the problem).

The tutorial uses `classes` in the controller index, zfcUser and the Skeleton using `invokables` but it doesnt seem to matter, as the error dont change.

my module.config currently looks like this:

```
<?php

return array(

    // Controllers in this module
    'controller' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'album/album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),        
    ),


    // Routes for this module
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'priority' => 1000,
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/album',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'album/album',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array( 
                    'misc' => array (
                        'type'    => 'segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/album/[:action][/:id]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'album/album',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),    

    // View setup for this module
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Album\Controller\AlbumController:

```
<?php

namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\ActionController,
    Zend\View\Model\ViewModel,
    Album\Model\AlbumTable,
    Album\Model\Album,
    Album\Form\AlbumForm;

class AlbumController extends ActionController
{
// [....]
}
```

I dont know where to look to fix this error, does someone of you have an idea?

Code is like orginal on github (see links above) when not mentioned otherwise.

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference here is not only the invokables, but also that the array key is now "controller**s**" in plural, wich did the trick for me. In your code "invokables" is already changed, but you seem to use "controller" as key.

```
    'controllers' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
                    'album/album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
            ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently there is a change in the array for the controller. Now the classes key is changed to invokables:
At the module.config.php

```
    'controller' => array(
            'classes' => array(
                    'album/album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
            ),
    ),
```

has to be changed to

```
    'controllers' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
                    'album/album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
            ),
    ),
```

Comment: Hello Rufinus, I had not noticed that in your code. The change solved the problem for me anyway.

Comment: +Armand i missed your change to "controller" as +sirkohli mentioned. i gave him the right answer flag, couse he is a new member. thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Found it, it The ActionController class seems to be gone on ZF2-beta4 so your AlbumController 
needs to be this way:

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController,
    Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController {
   .....
}
```

Comment: hi and welcome to SO. your are right, (intresting enough it doesnt throw an error with ActionController) but the routing problem isnt fix by it.

Comment: Same problem, changed to AbstractActionController and still have problems with the routing.

Comment: As Armand Says you need to change the module.config.php to invokables

Answer (score 0):

You must right config/application.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Album',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```