# router dont work in ZF 2beta5

Tags: zend-route, zend-framework2, zend-router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zend Framework 2 MVC - Modules Route mapping not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340932/zend-framework-2-mvc-modules-route-mapping-not-working)

My router was working in beta4 but isn't working in beta5.

Needed is Locale in url.
Option is namespace/module in url.

In module.config.php

```
return array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/[:locale[/:namespace[/:controller[/:action]]]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'locale' => '[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}',
                            'namespace' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'locale' => 'da_DK',
                            'namespace' => 'Application',
                            'controller' => 'index',
                            'action' => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ), ),
        'controller' => array(
            'classes' => array(
                'index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
            ),
        ), 
            ......
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They did some changes, so it's the controller-part that doesn't work. It has changed name to `controllers` (with an *s*), and instead of classes it should be `invokables` now.

So try:

```
'controllers' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
                'index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
            ),
),
```

Edit: if this fixed the issue, we actually have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11376305/923847).